# Is it OK to say *inflation is one of the most important in UK macroeconomics issues*?

Tags: grammar

Is it OK to say **inflation is one of the most important in UK macroeconomics issues**?

Comment: Proofreading? I think that it's just a grammar question, in fact. Not everybody knows how to ask a question so it pleases every single person....it's obvious the person is an English language learner...."Thanks for your guide"....? I mean....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your phrasing is correct, but to my ear it sounds better to say

**inflation is one of the most important issues in UK macroeconomics**

This is a bit closer to your original sentence than what others have suggested (although other ways work too).

Answer (score 2):

You may say whatever you like. In writing, however, better would be:

**Inflation is one of the UK's most important macro-economic issues**.

Another example of the same structure:

**Love is one of life's most important aspects**.